# How to get "Equal" (saturation, brightness) Red and Green Colours in a Web-based Application?

Tags: color, perspective, color-science, human-vision

I am looking for a red and a green hue that are equally discernable against a gray background on any PC monitor, using HTML/CSS-based application. There are many possible solutions to balance these factors, but none of them work well, and I don't know how to best implement it.

The gray could be a mid-gray (e.g., `#909090`). If, for example, I select a red and green similar in lightness and saturation `hsl(h*, 100%, 25.1%)`, red `RGB(128,0,0)`(`#800000`) and green `RGB(0,128,0)`(`#008000`), the result is, at least to my eyes, far from equal. Red-on-gray is definitely more discernable than green-on-gray see [image hsl red-on-gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9uWn.png) and [image hsl green-on-gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUWEI.png).

If I follow the CIELCh, wherein saturation can be defined as `sat = C*/L*` ([Wilms & Oberfeld, 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00426-017-0880-8)), a balanced pair could be this: **red** CIE-LCh°(ab) (D65/2°) = 34, 100, 57, `rgb(164, 14, 0)` (`#A40E00`, `hsl(5.1, 100%, 32.2%)`) and  **green** CIE-LCh°(ab) (D65/2°) = 34, 100, 150, `rgb(0, 103, 0)` (`#006700`, `hsl(120, 100%, 20.2%)`). Now, the lightness from the HSL model does not correspond anymore. How can I satisfy all colour models? Admittedly, or maybe I am just going crazy and see what I wanna see, the pictures with the CIELCh saturation balanced version seems a bit more balanced to me, see [image lch red-on-gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeE0k.png) and [image lch green-on-gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1j8h.png)

Also, I don't know how (much) the gray factors in here in the perception of the colours, since they aren't presented against white.

I have a specific aim in mind: I want to run an online study (using a JS/HTML/CSS application, hence preferably HEX colors). Of course it is not possible to achieve a perfect balance in an online study where we cannot know the properties of the monitors, but the main measure is within-subjects, hence it should not matter much if there are some differences to a certain extent.

**All in all, I just want to make sure that I use the "least worst" solution.**